# Is there a service for direct connectivity to Google Cloud?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

Is there a service available on Google Cloud for the direct connectivity between on-premise and the Google Cloud networks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Google Carrier Interconnect](https://cloud.google.com/interconnect/) as well as [Direct Peering](https://cloud.google.com/interconnect/direct-peering).

Answer (score 1):

There is [a VPN service](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn) for exactly that purpose. This is now in beta, so you should be able to use it.

You can of course also setup your own VPN solution, for example using OpenVPN.